# String is not parsing in JSONSerializer

Tags: json, jsonserializer, json-serialization

i have a json string like

**{"id":0,"version":0,"subject":"[2sravya]  data","description":"[10nd data] description [AWS Account:12234]","createdDate":null,"visibleToCustomer":false,"externalEMailId":null}**

After it is converted to JSONObject using JSONSerializer.toJSON() the JSONObject contains value like

**{
   "id": 0,
   "version": 0,
   "subject": "[2sravya]  fdaya",
   "description": [
      "10nd data"
   ]
}**

data present in description is a string data. i want the same to be present in formatted JSONObject.

Comment: description will parse to JSONArray and not String.

Comment: is there any case i send that description as string without converting it into JSONArray

Comment: Which is the language that you use to serialize/deserialize the JSON? Is it Java?Node?

Comment: using java JSONSerializer